# Getting "State is invalid" on return from Gmail API initial user consent completion

Tags: gmail-api

I have a basic process to get user consent for read-only access to their Gmail account via the API.  This overall process was working a week ago - tested multiple times both locally and running from the live web site.  Will describe technology in use at the end of this post.

The issue: as of this week I am able to get to the Gmail user login screens from my web app, can enter Gmail user/pwd but upon return from the API call I get a 500 (internal server) error on the live web site and a "State is invalid" when testing locally.  Another difference is that when running locally my code both receives and is able to store the access token values. The server side background sync process is able to use the access tokens to access/read Gmail account and refresh the token as necessary.  The tokens do not get collected and stored from the live site after user consent however.

Will post code blocks upon request but this is a pretty vanilla Gmail API auth process.

Technology:
VS2019 Pro *
.Net 4.8 *
C# MVC *
Gmail API w/OAuth2 *
AWS

Comment: please include your code.

Comment: Please include the code, remove sensitive info though.